# how to find length of an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

I am working with firebase for the first time. For that I am using Firestore. For getting all the messages I use Firebase built in method **querySnapshot**; Here i am getting all the rows as an object, where I declare a global variable as an array and try to push each and every object into that array. All was perfect. I got the array with all the messages as I want. But I want to get the length of an array. And I dont know every time I got **0** as an output where It have two rows.Lets Look at the Image for more better understanding
[image]

Please help me solve this..

[image]
Here is the utput i get

Comment: Please give a Log output of user_messages in showMessage. Empty ? Try showMessages(user_message) instead.

Comment: `.onSnapshot` might be an asynchronous method. So its callback will be called at a later time than the `console.log`. So call the `showMessages()` inside the onSnapshot callback, below the foreach loop.

Comment: edited the question and added the Output

Comment: In your browser console log, the reason why your console's message `length is = 0` is giving you a different value than when you click on the `[]` is because your console wont evaluate the array until you click on it, which by that time your snapshot handler has been called twice and your array has two elements.

Comment: yes @DylanLandry you are right...and your answer is solved my problems....But now i cannot accept the answer. I have to wait for 2minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onSnapshot` lets you listen for snapshots. That means that you cannot guarantee that your handler would have been called even once before `showMessages` is invoked.

You could reorder your control flow like this:

```js
// ...

user_chats.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        user_messages.push(doc.data());
    });
    showMessages();
});

// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose `showMessages()` called earlier than you push anything to `user_messages` array in `onSnapshot` callback.